# Comma usage in serial list with isolated speech word thrown in

Tags: oxford-comma

Consider the sentence:

> I like listening to hip hop, hard rock, and[,] ironically[,] classical music.

What is the proper way to punctuate "ironically" in that sentence? I put [] around where I am curious if there should be additional commas or maybe even semi-colon.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is a matter of style, so you might want to consult your manual of style, either the one you've adopted or the one thrust upon you.  I favor *The Chicago Manual of Style*, and I also recommend Steven Pinker's *The Sense of Style*.

Commas separate lists of unpunctuated items and also set off parenthetical elements.  Be kind to your readers and don't lead them down a garden path (Pinker's preferred description) by making them consider -- if only for a moment -- that "ironically" belongs in the list.  You, as I, have available dashes and parentheses for our asides:

> I like listening to hip hop, hard rock, and (ironically) classical
>   music
>   I like listening to hip hop, hard rock, and -- ironically -- classical
>   music